# How to access User Admin in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed Postgres 12 with PgAdmin4 on Ubuntu, I installed normal and I'm logging in with the postgres user but I see in the root of the PgAdmin there is a server called localhost, when I want to access that localhost it asks me for the password of the user(user) 'admin'. This user comes by default? What is your password? or which Postgres file I need to modify to access the localhost

[image]

Comment: What version of ubuntu?  What minor version of PostgreSQL v12?  What version of pgAdmin4?  desktop mode or web mode? How did you install? Had pgAdmin4 previously been installed on the system and then removed?

Comment: Is it an old version in I had installed, how can I remove it??

Comment: If pgadmin is just remembering some old registration for a server that no longer exists, all you need to do is remove it from pgadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the pattern password is 'postgres'

Comment: s it an old version in I had installed, how can I remove it??

Comment: What is the version?